# Is it possible to set backgroud and background image at the same time with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Whenever I try to set both background and background-image property through javascript, I only get background peroperty on the element. Why is this happening? Did I miss something?

```
divelement.style.background = "url('one.png')"
divelement.style.backgroundImage = "url('two.png')"

// only gets..

<div style="background-image: url("one.png");">
```

Comment: How should the two background images be displayed? With same position?

Comment: It happens because `background` is a short hand property which also sets `background-image` hence overwrites it

Comment: @LGSon Perfect explanation :) Just about to post the same thing.

Comment: Thanks LGSon, you should post the answer.

Comment: @narusawa There is enough answer already cover it.

Comment: How does CSS background proprety work then? I see background and background-image property used together in this tutorial : [link](http://callmenick.com/post/nicer-icon-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions). Is there any way I can achieve the same effect through javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set **multiple backgrounds** in a single statement:

```
divelement.style.background = "url('one.png'), url('two.png')";
```

In your code, you are overriding one background with the other, as both `background` and `background-image` css properties can set a background image.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to set multiple `backgroundImage` at `style` attribute. You can use `backgroundPosition` to adjust image positions to display more than single `backgroundImage`

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
div.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics),\
  url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature)";
div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px 0px, 50px 0px";
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: nicely argumented answer :)

Comment: or you can use images with transparency

Comment: Four background images using `backgroundPosition` at one `div` element https://jsfiddle.net/bb8gt9x1/

Comment: How does CSS background proprety work then? I see background and background-image property used together in this tutorial : [link](http://callmenick.com/post/nicer-icon-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions) Is there any way I can achieve the same effect through javascript?

Comment: @narusawa What do you mean by "achieve the same effect"? Are you attempting to transition from one background image to a different background image with a sliding effect at `:hover` of the element? Note, original Question does not describe an issue with rendering an "effect"?

Comment: Yes. In order to do that, the javascript equivalent I thought would be setting both style.background and style.backgroundImage, which is obviously not working. I guess there is no alternative to set both properties through javascript?

Comment: @narusawa You can set multiple `backgroundImage` values at single property, as demonstrated at stacksnippets, jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bb8gt9x1/. `javascript` is not actually necessary to render a sliding or rotating effect; you can use `css` `transition` or `animation`, `:hover` to achieve an effect which appears to animate or change background image. The same or similar effect can be rendered using `requestAnimationFrame` or recursion.